# Redirecting to alternative page if a linked document from <a> not found

Tags: html, redirect, hyperlink

I'm looking to see if there is some way to provide an alternative link for a hyperlink to follow if the primary doesn't exist, similar to an image 'alt'. I know 'onerror' exists but it doesnt seem to work for html links. I'd like to avoid JS if possible. If its unavoidable I'm willing to explore its options however.

So in short, if I use:

```
<a href="TestFile.html"> Link </a>
```

If it cant find 'TestFile.html', I'd like it to redirect to somewhere else, say TestFile2.html.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="onclick()">redirect</button>

<script>
const fs = require('fs')

const path = './TestFile.html'

function onclick() {
try {
if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
//file exists
return res.redirect('/server/TestFile.html'); 
  }
} catch(err) {
//file unknown
return res.redirect('/server/TestFile2.html'); 
}}
</script>
```

This should work! But it might not, because I suck at coding and this is a Frankenstein of multiple online sources. Thank You!

Comment: Unfortunately this HTML is for a documentation system which doesnt use any Node systems, as its all client side. So 'fs' cant be used.